# How many ways can $720$ be decomposed into a product of two positive integers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> How many ways can $720$ be decomposed into a product of two positive integers?

**My solution:** There are $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 30$ ways to choose the exponents a, b, c, such that $2^a \cdot 3^b \cdot 5^c= 720$. Soon there are $30$ dividers. As there are $30$ dividers, there are $\frac{30}{2} = 15$ different products in the form $xy=720$

**Question:** We want $ab$ such that $a,b \in \{2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2\}$, that is, we want combinations of these possible values of $a$ and $b$, such that $ab=720$. How could I solve this problem following this line of reasoning? A different solution from mine (Using counting principles)

Comment: In my opinion your method is fastest.

Comment: $720 = a \cdot b = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$. So one of the two numbers will have $5$ as a factor, For other factors to go along with $5$ - we have $5$ choices for power of $2$ ($0$-$4$) and $3$ choices for power of $3$ ($0$ - $2$). That gives $5 \cdot 3 = 15$.

Comment: About your second method, I do not understand what you are trying to do. Can you explain a bit?

Comment: @coffeemath I don't want a necessarily quick method

Comment: @MathLover How can I make a combination of $a$ and $b$ such that $ab = 720$, that is, enforcing this condition?

Comment: The square root of $720$ is $26...$ so count all numbers $ \le 26$ which have $2, 3, 5$ as factors with powers $\le 4, \le 2, \le 1$ resp. That gives all numbers except $7, 11, 13, 14, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26$. That is $11$ numbers. So the answer should be $26 - 11 = 15$

Comment: $3^3 \gt 26, 2^5 \gt 26$, only $5^2 \lt 26$. So to count numbers that would not work, in addition to $25$, I only counted prime numbers starting from $7$ and their multiples.

Comment: @MathLover I didn't think about it that way. I thought it was possible to make some kind of combination with some condition imposed. Your method seems to be more work anyway. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{align*}
720 & = 2 \cdot 360\\
    & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 180\\
    & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 90\\
    & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 45\\
    & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 15\\
    & = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 5\\
    & = 2^4 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5
\end{align*}
each factor must be of the form $2^a3^b5^c$.

Suppose the factors are $2^{a_1}3^{b_1}5^{c_1}$ and $2^{a_2}3^{b_2}5^{c_2}$.  Observe that
\begin{align*}
a_1 + a_2 & = 4 \tag{1}\\
b_1 + b_2 & = 2 \tag{2}\\
c_1 + c_2 & = 1 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
are equations in the nonnegative integers.

The equation
$$x_1 + x_2 = n$$
has $n + 1$ solutions in the nonnegative integers, namely $$(n, 0), (n - 1, 1), (n - 2, 2), \ldots, (2, n - 2), (1, n - 1), (0, n)$$
Hence, equation 1 has five solutions, equation 2 has three solutions, and equation 2 has two solutions.  Hence, there are $5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 = 30$ ordered pairs of factors with product $720$.  Since $720$ is not a perfect square, each ordered pair consists of two distinct numbers.  Since we do not care about the order of the factors, we must divide this result by two.  Thus, the number of ways to decompose $720$ into two positive integer factors is
$$\frac{5 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{2} = 15$$

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be another approach:

We want $ab=720$. Since we have $2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2$ and we want this to form the product of 2 primes such that it results in $720$, then:
$$\binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2} \cdot  \binom{2}{2}= 30.$$ But since we ended up counting the possibilities twice (for example: if $a=2$, then $b=360$; if $b=2$, then $a=360$), then we have $\frac{30}{2}=15$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you're thinking of $ { 5 \choose 2 }$? EG If we pick $\{3, 4 \}, \{1, 3 \}, \{1, 2 \}$, then what values of $a, b$ does that map onto? $\quad$ To be clear, I don't think your solution works, and you just happen to find values that multiplied to 30.

Comment: For example, if we wanted $ ab  = 2^{99}$, then are there $ { 100 \choose 2 } / 2 $ such pairs, or just $100/2$ such pairs?

Comment: @CalvinLin Because we can make a combination of $5$ elements $2$ (ie $2 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot 2 $), taken $2$ to $2$. It would be $2$ dismembering as elements. As for your question, I think we would have $\displaystyle \frac{100}{2}$

Comment: The point is, I'm multiplying the combinations, so we wouldn't just have the combinations with the $2$ exponents, but the $3$ and $5$ exponents as well.

Comment: What about $ ab = 2^{99} 3^{99}$? Are there $ { 100 \choose 2 } { 100 \choose 2 } / 2 $ such pair?